# Smart contract in peer-to-peer network without existence of blockchain

Tags: p2p, smartcontracts

I need to know how can apply smart contract in a peer-to-peer network in which blockchain has not been utilized.

think two entities are interacting together in a peer-to-peer network and they have obligated pay some cost for some service that provide together ,but in this case they don't use blockchain and they should pay inside the network,can they use smart contract in this case? smart contract without blockchain? is any solution or any sample for that?

Answer (score 0):

So far smart contracts have only been implemented in blockchain networks (and other distributed ledgers such as Hashgraph). Without such a platform you need some intermediary to fill the role of a smart contract.

For P2P networks, Bitcoin (and it's successors) were the first to create virtual currency in a decentralized fashion - so no, it is not possible to use digital currency without blockchain or a trusted third party.